# Master Faders, AUXs - 48 bit vs 24 bit in stem/mixing workflows

Tags: mixing, stems, bit-depth

So, I've been thinking a bit about mix workflows and routing.

In the past, with dialogue, for example, I've hard-bussed all my dx tracks to an aux track where I normally just throw a bit of compression. That aux track feeds my stem audio track, which in turn feeds my printmaster audio track.

I recently saw a posting talking about master faders, though, and at some point Brent Heber mentioned that master faders are within the 48 bit realm whereas aux tracks are in the 24 bit realm. So, master faders have more dynamic range and a lower noise floor.

So, is it actually preferable to be using master faders over aux tracks for things like bus compression? Is it really going to be affecting my mix?

Furthermore, I'm also kind of wondering about how this whole bit resolution thing works with audio tracks. Let's say that I had 16 tracks, and I wanted to print them down to 4 or 8 tracks with a bit of preliminary subtractive EQ, maybe NR, whatnot, prior to the final mix. Would I be sacrificing something if I didn't, instead, keep those tracks, as they were, up through the final mix when they get laid back into the stem and/or pmaster?

Thanks. Hope this wasn't too confusing.

Comment: This might help: http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/white_paper/en365855?popup=true No guarantees on the validity of information provided though.